# How to (salt and hash) and store a password in java..Then check the password if matches to a user's manual input

Tags: java, passwords, salt

So im coding a register and a log-in system in java. My plan for the register is: the user enters username, then enters password.

The password gets salted and stored in a .txt file.
Now when user will have to enter the password to the log-in system, how i retrieve the original password to check it from the .txt file since its salted?

My questions are two:
how i salt the password and then store it.
How to retrieve the original password, so to check it.

I have searched a lot of things but i found nothing about this.

Comment: As far as I know you should salt and encrypt passwords and save them that way. Then you should salt and encrypt the entered password and check that they match, but never be able to retrieve the original one. If you can retrieve the original one then it's not safe

Comment: Your terminology is wrong. My guess is that you salt and **hash** the password. salting consists in appending or prepending some random value to the password. Hashing consists in applying a cryptographic digest function to the salt+password. By definition, a digest is one way. If you could find back the password from the hash, it would defeat the whole purpose of a hash, which is precisely to prevent that. You need to salt the password from the user with the same salt, apply the same cryptographic digest, and compare the new hash with the stored one.

Comment: @JB Nizet you are right. This is what i need. Where i can find something like that because i have no idea in general about cryptography

Comment: See https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/globe42/blob/master/backend/src/main/kotlin/org/globe42/web/security/PasswordDigester.kt for an example (in Kotlin, but it's very close to Java).

Answer (score 0):

You save both the salted password and the salt. So when saving the password you do the following:

- create a salt (random hash of a certain length)
- hash the password + salt combination
- store this hashed string, but also store the salt and the username.

Do NOT store the plaintext password!

When a user tries to log in later, you do the following:

- retrieve the hashed password and salt (stored together with the username, so look up by username)
- hash the password (provided by user who wants to log in) + salt
- compare this hashed string with the hashed password you stored.
- If they are equal, the user provided the correct password.

So you never compare the plaintext password a user provides with a plaintext password you saved, because it is unsecure to save plaintext passwords, in case this data gets compromised.

Comment: this is exaclty what i need. But im new to cryptography, and i have zero knowledge in general. Where i can find something like this you described me?

Comment: Please, don't use the term "encrypt". What is needed is a one waht hash, or digest. Not encryption. Encryption consists in using a key to encrypt, and a key to decrypt and find the original text back. That's not what should be used here.

Comment: [this blog](https://auth0.com/blog/adding-salt-to-hashing-a-better-way-to-store-passwords/) gives quite a good explanation why you should use unique salts (to prevent rainbow table attacks). Or is your question more what Java code you should write?